# how to do smart data analysis when you have a lot of variables

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm new here, I work a lot with marketing analysis. Most times, I receive a giant base with a lot of variables (`10 - 15`) and people ask me: with the variables that we have(age, sex, etc.), what does explain the growing or the falling revenue?

I usually do this looking at the graphs and analyzing every possible case, but I really believe that there is a better way to do that.

```
age   sex     business_unit year  month revenue name  
10-20 Male    unit_1       2018    1     $100   chloe  
20-30 Female  unit_2       2019    2     $250   arnold
```

I was thinking if there is a way that combines every possible variable and gives me the variation, like:

```
age    revenue   
10-20  -$100    year over year  

sex  revenue  
male -$200   year over year  

age   sex   revenue   
10-20 male   -$50   year over year
```

and every other possible combination. Is there a way to do that? With Python?

Answer (score 1):

A nice tool to visualise the relationships between each pair of your variables is the 'corner' module.

This allows you to plot the distributions of each of your variables and see how they depend on the others. e.g

https://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom.html

[image: Example output from corner.py]

Using the 'quantiles' keyword you can plot the 16th and 84th percentiles on your data etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use **Multiple Linear Regression** model on your dataset

by doing that you will get a formula that should predict the `y` variable (lets say revenue) based on all other variables like `y=c1*x1-c2*x2...`

the coefficient `c` can tell you how much this variable effect the `y`. so in a case where `revenue = 2*age + -0.5*sex...` the age has a positive double impact on the revenue and sex has negative (and 4 times less important than `age`)

if you would like all relationship between all variables, you will have to run 10 to 15 models, in each model the `y` will represent some other variable from age, sex, revenue and such

you can check this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-linear-regression-in-python-with-scikit-learn-83a8f7ae2b4f) for how to implement it with python